# Load next set of content with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-routing

I recently have been working with Angular and I'm struggling with this.  My API route is

```
file/50/0
```

where 50 is the number of items to return, and 0 is the page number.  Although I've been having trouble trying to implement an Angular process to change the information to

```
file/50/1
```

I am trying to implement an Ng-Click directive for this (since my user wants a button).  I am using ng-repeat within  a table format to display the data

Here is my table:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="information in app.info">
        <td>{{information.uuid}}</td>
        <td>{{information.publisher}}</td>
    </tr
</table>
```

I wish to implement something along the lines of:

```
<button ng-click="decrement()"> Decrement </button>
<button ng-click="increment()"> Increment </button>
```

Also my original API call is along the lines of

```
$http.get("/file/50/0")
.success(function(data){
    app.info=data;
});
```

Edit:  To clarify "decrement()" and "increment()" don't do anything yet, I'm trying to make these functions load the next set of data, so from "/file/50/0" - > "/file/50/1".  Or "file/50/1" - > "file/50/0".

Comment: what is decrement() and increment() doing in the controller?  might be work making a jsfiddle with an example

Comment: @Dreamwalker They aren't doing anything yet, they're just example function names I want to implement.  I want increment() to grab /file/50/1 and then switch the data that is called into the table (I assume it would have to be a rewrite/ redraw), and so on everytime it is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pageYou can Use this like 
'

```
 <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="information in app.info">
            <td>{{information.uuid}}</td>
            <td>{{information.publisher}}</td>
        </tr>
      <button ng-click="getData('{{page}}'+1)"> Decrement </button>
      <button ng-click="getData('{{page}}'-1)"> Increment </button>
    </table>
```

`

In your controller you can add this

```
$scope.page= 0;//get the first page, always check with min and max values of pages
$scope.getData= function(page){
$http.get("/file/50/"+page).success(function(data){
 app.info=data;
 $scope.page= page;
});
}
```

Comment: When I change my code to yours and rerun I get an output of `"Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'page' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 11 of the expression [getData({{page}}+1)] starting at [page}}+1)].`

Comment: u can this getData method as getData('{{page}}'+1) and do remember that page value should be initialized in the controller